# Can raku avoid this Malformed UTF-8 error?

Tags: unicode, raku

When I run this raku script...

```
my $proc = run( 'tree', '--du', :out);
$proc.out.slurp(:close).say;
```

I get this error on MacOS...

```
Malformed UTF-8 near bytes ef b9 5c
```

... instead of something like this **tree** output from zsh which is what I want...

```
.
├── 00158825_20210222_0844.csv
├── 1970-Article\ Text-1971-1-2-20210118.docx
├── 1976-Article\ Text-1985-1-2-20210127.docx
├── 2042-Article\ Text-2074-1-10-20210208.pdf
├── 2045-Article\ Text-2076-1-10-20210208.pdf
├── 6.\ Guarantor\ Form\ (A).pdf
```

I have tried `slurp(:close, enc=>'utf8-c8')` and the error is the same.

I have also tried...

```
 shell( "tree --du >> .temp.txt" );
 my @lines = open(".temp.txt").lines;
 dd @lines;
```

... and the error is the same.

Opening .temp.txt reveals this...

```
.
â<94><9c>â<94><80>â<94><80> [    1016739]  True  
â<94><9c>â<94><80>â<94><80> [ 9459042241]  dir-name
â<94><82>Â Â  â<94><9c>â<94><80>â<94><80> [     188142]  Business
â<94><82>Â Â  â<94><82>Â Â  â<94><9c>â<94><80>â<94><80> [       9117]  KeyDates.xlsx
â<94><82>Â Â  â<94><82>Â Â  â<94><9c>â<94><80>â<94><80> [      13807]  MondayNotes.docx
```

file -I gives this...

```
.temp.txt: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
```

Any advice?

[this is Catalina 10.15.17, Terminal encoding Unicode(UTF-8)
Welcome to ™ v2020.10.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.10.]

Comment: Try opening the `.temp.txt` file using UTF-8 encoding…

Comment: ```my @lines = open(".temp.txt", enc=>'utf8').lines;``` also throws ```Malformed UTF-8 near bytes ef b9 5c```

Comment: sooo  - I tried all the enc values listed at https://docs.raku.org/routine/encoding and found that ```my @lines = open(".temp.txt", enc=>'utf8-c8').lines;``` is the only one that can read the file fairly well --- sadly that does not port back to eg. ```my $proc = run( 'tree', '--du', :out); my @lines = $proc.out.lines(:close, enc => 'utf8-c8'); say @lines;
```

Comment: @JosefZ - thanks for the hint - at least I can now run the tree cmd out to a temp file and read it back in again - not optimal, but it works! [I will hold off accepting your answer to see if anyone can resolve this for "run"]

Comment: Maybe set the encoding for the run `my $proc = run( 'tree', '--du', enc => 'utf8-c8', :out);` ?

Comment: hi @ValleLukas - yes, that works! [I had not appreciated that run can take the enc adverb-rtfm!]... my impression is that this is needed to condition the encoding on the out pipe BEFORE you get to proc.out.lines...

Comment: epilog: this issue also arises in python shell call to tree in macos .. imo the underlying issue is most likely a tree-codepage setting done wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you have a codepage/locale that is not Utf8. (Or `tree` is ignoring the codepage and using something different.)

A quick … get something, anything out of it; is to use an 8-bit single-byte encoding.

```raku
run( 'tree', '--du', :out, :enc<latin1> );
```

It generally is enough to see where decoding starts to go wrong with Utf8.

---

That said, let's look at your expected output, and the file output.

```raku
say '├──'.encode; # utf8:0x<E2 94 9C E2 94 80 E2 94 80>
```

In your file you have

```
â<94><9c>â<94><80>â<94><80> [    1016739]  True
```

Wait …

```raku
say 'â'.encode('latin1'); # Blob[uint8]:0x<E2>
```

```
<E2><94><9c><E2><94><80><E2><94><80>

       <E2 94 9c E2 94 80 E2 94 80>

utf8:0x<E2 94 9C E2 94 80 E2 94 80>
```

Yeah, those look an awful lot alike.
In that they are exactly the same.

So it does appear to be producing the expected output to some extent.

Which seems to confirm, that yes there is an encoding problem in-between `tree` and your code. That indicates that the codepage/locale is set wrong.

---

You haven't really provided enough information to figure out exactly what's going wrong where.
You should have used `run` in binary mode to give us the exact output.

```perl
say run('echo', 'hello', :out, :bin).out.slurp;
# Buf[uint8]:0x<68 65 6C 6C 6F 0A>
```

You also didn't say if `<9c>` is literally in the file as four text characters, or if it is a feature of whatever you used to open the file turning binary data into text.

It also would be nice if all of the example data was of the same thing.

---

On a slightly related note…

Since `tree` gives filenames, and **filenames are not Unicode**, using `utf8-c8` is appropriate here.
(Same generally goes for usernames and passwords.)

Here's some code that I ran on my computer to hopefully show why.

```raku
say dir(:test(/^ r.+sum.+ $/)).map: *.relative.encode('utf8-c8').decode
# (résumé résumé résumé résumé)

dir(:test(/^ r.+sum.+ $/)).map: *.relative.encode('utf8-c8').say
# Blob[uint8]:0x<72 65 CC 81 73 75 6D 65 CC 81>
# Blob[uint8]:0x<72 C3 A9 73 75 6D 65 CC 81>
# Blob[uint8]:0x<72 C3 A9 73 75 6D C3 A9>
# Blob[uint8]:0x<72 65 CC 81 73 75 6D C3 A9>

say 'é'.NFC;
# NFC:0x<00e9>
say 'é'.NFD
# NFD:0x<0065 0301>

sub to-Utf8 ( Uni:D $_ ){
   .map: *.chr.encode
}

say to-Utf8 'é'.NFC
# (utf8:0x<C3 A9>)
say to-Utf8 'é'.NFD
# (utf8:0x<65> utf8:0x<CC 81>)
```

So `é` is either encoded as one composed codepoint `<C3 A9>` or two decomposed codepoints `<65> <CC 81>`.

Did I really create 4 files with the “same name” just for this purpose?
Yes. Yes I did.

Comment: Hi Brad ... many thanks for your answer, which works for me. (i) latin-1 solves the problem in that the 'Malformed' error is gone and the bulk of the chars are fine (ie. I do not care if the unicode? decorators '├──' are not rendering tidily)  (ii) apologies that the "what I want" example was different - I thought it would be good enough to provide a sample (iii) <9c> is what I get when I open the file with vi (set fileencodings=utf-8 set encoding=utf-8) ... that's a good caveat.

Comment: @p6steve I would still try to find out and fix the mojibake problem. It appears that the output may be getting incorrectly encoded a second time by your shell/OS as `'â'.encode` is `utf8:0x<C3 A2>` not `0x<E2>` as the bytes should be. So it seems like your shell incorrectly thinks `tree` is outputting `latin1` when it is actually outputting `Utf8`.

Answer (score 3):

**Update** I had deleted this nanswer because Brad's excellent answer and Valle Lukas's spot on comment seemed to render it moot. Then @p6steve confirmed both Brad's answer and Valle Lukas's solutions worked for them, so all the more reason to keep it deleted. But too late! A mistake in my nanswer had misled @p6steve who made a similar mistake in a follow up SO. Wea Culpa. To atone for my sins, I'm now permanently undeleting and leaving my shameful past for all to see.

---

This is a nanswer. I don't know Mac, but do love investigation, and what I've got to say won't fit in the comments.

---

**Update** The `'find .'` in the following should be `'find', '.'`. See [`run` doc](https://docs.raku.org/routine/run).

What do you get with this?:

```
say .out.lines given run 'find .', :out
```

If `find .` works, the problem is presumably `tree`.

If `find .` doesn't work, then try something really simple, that's built into MacOS, something that really should work. If it doesn't work, then the problem isn't `tree` but something more basic.

---

> Malformed UTF-8 near bytes ef b9 5c

That means Raku was expecting UTF-8 but the input wasn't UTF-8.

Translating the message from computerese into English:

> The supposedly English string ["[Linux] xshell远程登陆CentOS时中文乱码解决_Cindy的博客 ...](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E6%80%8E%E9%BA%BC%E6%A8%A3%E4%BA%86%3F&op=translate)" is Malformed near `远程登`.

In other words, the `tree` command is not generating UTF-8.

(Therefore using `utf8-c8` will almost certainly be useless in the first instance. Its purpose is to cheat. It's for when text is either *almost* all UTF-8 except for a handful of rogue bytes, and you can't be bothered to sort out the input, or when you have absolutely no choice but to accept the input as it is and still want to muddle through. But in this case you surely ought either sort the problem out by getting to the bottom of things, or find some alternative to `tree`.)

---

> Terminal encoding Unicode(UTF-8)

A [google for "Terminal encoding Unicode(UTF-8)"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Terminal+encoding+Unicode%28UTF-8%29%22) yields just 7 matches. None appeared to be exact matches for "Terminal encoding Unicode(UTF-8)". All but one look to me like ... `ef b9 5c` looks to Rakudo. :)

If you copy/pasted that string, where did you copy it from?

If you yourself wrote that string, why were you so sure MacOS really *was* encoding `tree`'s output as UTF-8 when run via the kernel (not a shell) that you wrote that it was?

---

`run` doesn't use a shell.

---

[The current doc claims `shell` uses `/bin/sh -c` on MacOS](https://docs.raku.org/routine/shell).

What's the output of this?:

```
readlink -e $(which sh)
```

Is the output `zsh`?

If so `sh -c` should be using it.

If not, that may be the problem.

---

When one uses `shell`, one has to ensure the passed string is appropriately quoted and escaped. What do you get when you try these?:

```
say .out.lines given shell "'find .'", :out;
say .out.lines given shell "'tree --du'", :out;
```

---

What exactly is `tree` invoking? Is it a shell alias in `zsh`? If it's a binary, where did you install it from and how did you configure it, especially in terms of influencing `zsh`'s handling of encodings?