# raku run('find .', :out); not working on MacOS

Tags: raku

While testing around this issue, [Can raku avoid this Malformed UTF-8 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617385/can-raku-avoid-this-malformed-utf-8-error?noredirect=1#comment117765340_66617385) it was suggested that I try using the built in MacOS 'find .' command with the raku run function.

```
1 #!/usr/local/bin/raku
2 
3 shell('find .');                    #works
4 
5 my $proc = run('find .', :out);     #fails with
6 $proc.out.lines(:close).say;        #() [ie. ().Seq]
```

Turns out that raku shell works fine, but raku run fails. I am not entirely sure if this is a bug with raku on MacOS (if so, I am happy to report it) ...?

[MacOS Catalina 10.15.17 ... Welcome to ™ v2020.10. Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d. Built on MoarVM version 2020.10.]

Comment: Mea culpa. I was the one who suggested the bogus `run 'find .'`. (It was in a nanswer I later deleted. I had a point, but my entire nanswer became moot when Brad's answer and Valle Lucas's comment arrived.) I just about *always* test code in anything I write, but skipped that particular code because I don't have a Mac and thought "what can go wrong in 12 characters of dead simple code?" despite knowing Murphy chuckles at such thoughts. Apologies for the noise, but I can confidently predict I will make similar mistakes again and y'all will forgive me because y'all love me. Right? :)

Comment: my fault too - I did read the docs and I did try the @codesections version to eliminate as a possibility before posting this question - sooo ... looks like I somehow miskeyed it -  suggest we leave it in for future reference since folks coming from eg. perl may not immediately 'get' the shell-less run syntax??

Comment: the state contained here works for me - the other SO is only half answered, this one is 100% clear

Comment: Wea Culpa. @p6steve: I've undeleted my nanswer in the prior SO. Hopefully that's what you meant by "the other SO is only half answered". If you didn't mean that, I'd need clarification of what you meant if I were to try address it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you're running encountering isn't related to MacOS – it's caused by the difference in how `&shell` and `&run` work. Consulting the docs, we can see that [shell](https://docs.raku.org/language/independent-routines#sub_shell)'s signature  includes `$cmd` – the command as a `Str`, exactly as you provided.

In contrast, [run](https://docs.raku.org/language/independent-routines#sub_run)'s signature specifies that it takes `*@args` – that is, a list of zero or more arguments to execute.

To match this signature, you should change your code as shown below:

```
# my $proc = run('find .', :out);     # doesn't work
  my $proc = run('find', '.', :out);  # works
  my $p2   = run <find .>, :out;      # also works (using word-splitting)
```

(Your version asked your computer to run the program `find .`, which doesn't exist in your `$PATH`, which explains why it produced no output.)